# bindActionCreators, @connect in React-Redux and understanding the code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I was trying to comprehend this code on [github](https://github.com/dvalchanov/react-redux-2048/blob/master/src/scripts/containers/Game.js)

Here they programmer have used something like this

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.actions = bindActionCreators(Actions, this.props.dispatch);
  }
```

**Question 1:** Here,  `this.actions = bindActionCreators(Actions, this.props.dispatch);` doesn't make sense to me

Also, This isn't primary question but from where I learned React-redux, we used to connect component like this

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, 
  {fetchCoin, 
    updateCrypto, 
    CurrencyRate,
    CurrencyState
  })(cryptoTicker);
```

In the above code Snippet the programmer have done something like this

```
@connect(state => {
  return {
    score: state.game.get("score"),
    result: state.game.get("result")
  };
})
```

**Question 2: ** Which again sort of looks alien to me (like I have few months of experience using js but this is the first time I am encountering **`@`**) So can someone please explain me what is **@** in general in JS?

And lastly he have declared two functions which are being called `onclick` after return statement of class

```
 _handleNewGame = () => {
    this.actions.initGame();
  }

  /**
   * Save the current game`s state.
   */
  _handleSaveGame = () => {
    this.actions.saveGame();
  }
```

Now Since I am still relatively new to JS and react, I have two questions for this part

**Question 3:** Can we create a function inside a class after return and render? If yes then wouldn't it have been a good practise (in general) to create a function before render where all the other functions are declared?

Comment: It appears the github code you're referenced is a couple years old. I highly recommend following the example on the official Redux site (https://redux.js.org/basics/exampletodolist) to understand how the code works. For example, the official site uses non-decorator syntax which i find to be easier to understand than @connect.

Comment: @ShawnAndrews even i use the same way (as shown in question) but I am just trying to comprehend his code. Either way, can you answer the other two part of the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For question #1 and #2, your '@connect' and 'connect(mapStateToProps, ...)(cryptoTicker)' syntax is equivalent. The @ indicates to the parser that we're using a decorator for our function, the connect(...) function, and outputs the same class, in this case Game, but with added functionality. This is called a HoC (Higher Order Components) design pattern and you can read more about it here https://medium.com/@mappmechanic/react-utility-higher-order-components-as-decorators-tc39-stage-2-9e9f3a17688a

For question #3, you are correct, it is better practice to leave the render function for the last function in the component.